# Can you send information to your server securely without https?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, https

I have a regular website with no login process. There was never anything on it that needed to be private so I'm using http. However I recently added an "E-mail Me" form, and some people might include sensitive information emailing me.

1. If the data is sent to my server with an Ajax `$.post`, can the data be read by someone watching the network traffic?
2. If so, Is there anyway I can secure it without switching to https?

OK:  So def Yes to no 1.

For everyone that said no, why can't I use my own public-key/private-key for this?

Comment: No, it's not secure

Comment: The short answer is no - this is why there is https. The long answer is yes - if you really want to create your own encryption protocol (which you don't).

Comment: Sensitive information is not the only reason for https. It is prudent to always use it.

Comment: @Crowcoder exactly ... other reasons such as [_being faster_](http://www.httpvshttps.com/) ...

Comment: Read [this](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/encrypt-in-transit/why-https?hl=en)

Comment: You can create a self-signed SSL certificate if you want to use HTTPS but don't want to purchase a verified cert from a Certificate Authority. There are some important discrepancies you should be aware of, if you decide to go the self-signed route. Untrusted certs are rejected by end-users but if the only reason you want to secure something is for personal use, go ahead an use one. If you need others to access the site publicly, no one will trust your site.

Answer (score 1):

> If the data is sent to my server with an Ajax $.post, can the data be read by someone watching the network traffic?

Yes, for sure

> If so, Is there anyway I can secure it without switching to https?

No, not really/practically.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use https, there is no other way to truly secure the information

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is NO.
The long answer is that if you use js, the person monitoring the traffic will be able to know how you encode the data and easily decode it. If you use server side language (C# for example), the data will be transmitted as plain text to the server so the person monitoring the traffic will be able to read it clearly.
The only way is that you use a secure connection (HTTPS)